# How can i print the dates of the first five month of a given year in the format below

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want to print the dates of the  first 5 months in a given year with the formats below.

> 2019-05,
>     2019-04,
>     2019-03, 
>     2019-02,
>     2019-01

Im using a for loop to achieve this

```
    var  first5monthIn2019 : [String]{
    var dates : [String] = []
    for i in 01...05 {
        dates.append("2019-0\(i)")
    }
      return dates
    }
```

Is there any accepted approach using `NSdate` to achieve the above.

Comment: What exactly you want you question says you want first 5 month of a year and in your approach you code for getting 5 days of a month ?

Comment: @Abhishek instead of downcasting my question , it would have been helpful if you suggested an edit

Comment: How about `NSDateComponents`?

Comment: @Willeke `NSDateComponents ` ? how is that achievable ?

Comment: First of all i haven't down vote your question, and surely i want to help but the thing is I'm not able to understand whether you're asking for first 5 day of month or first 5 month of a year.

Comment: @Abhishek , kindly see the update of the question.

Comment: Read the documentation of `NSDateComponents`. Have a try and ask a question here if you get stuck.

Comment: @Willeke , Thanks for the direction.Your comment should have been an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with DateComponents

```
for month in 1...5 {
    if let date = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2019, month: month, day: 1).date {
        print(date)
    }
}
```